# How to automatically say yes to prompt window

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that opens the book1.xlsm file as a read only file but I get the prompt window "Book1.xlsm is already open. Reopening will cause any changes you made to be discarded. Do you want to reopen Book.1" How do I have it say yes automatically so the user doesn't see it?

I have done this before but I cant seem to remember how.
I thought it was `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` but its not working so I am not sure...

Thanks

Code:

```
If MsgBox("Open as Read only?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\aholiday\Desktop\Book1", ReadOnly:=True
MsgBox ("Complete")
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Else
    MsgBox ("Editing Avaliable")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`?

Comment: Yup! that did it! I knew it was something simple.

Comment: Cool, I'll stick it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839782.aspx).

It's worth nothing that Excel will set this property to true once the executing code has finished.